# Secondary (extended) monitor turns off when I remove power cable from my laptop

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, thinkpad, external-display

I have a 2 monitor setup. An extended monitor that connects to my Lenovo Thinkpad T530. When I removes power cable from my laptop to run it on battery, the secondary (extended) monitor turns off. Can anyone help me in this regard?

Comment: Can you reactivate the display with Win-P or the Screen Resolution Control Panel?

Comment: Hi Daniel B, I tried but it doesn't work out. I even tried to make the extended monitor as primary display but no luck. FYI, I am using Dell E series E2213 monitor.

Comment: How are they connected: via DVI(VGA), HDMI or some exotic way like m a y b e USB-connection?
Anyway, click on "Default" at Windows advanced power settings and try to override any power management soft (if some) provided by laptops manufacturer.

Comment: On my T530, I currently have two external screens (one 5 year old Samasung & and 10 year old IBM)+ the laptop screen. Unplugs power -> stays the same. Could be you power setup?